# Dog registration - Australia - moving around areas

Tags: australia, pets, melbourne, registration, tasmania

Apologies if this is not in correct area.
I will try to be as clear as possible!

I am from the UK so I have little knowledge of this - I have looked up information but cannot seem to find anything specific to my situation.

I moved to Australia from the UK last week with my dog. My dog is coming out of quarantine in Melbourne at the end of this week. We are in a hotel in Melbourne waiting for him at the moment.

Once we get the dog we are going for a trip to Tasmania for around 2 1/2 months to visit family/holiday etc. We will then be moving back to Melbourne and will have found a permanent address. (Melbourne is where we will be living permanently after the trip).

Dog registration - to apply/forms etc - seems easy. Do I just register the dog once we are back in Melbourne as we need an address to register? Or am I going to have to register in Tasmania then re-register in Melbourne?

I can't seem to find information where you can 'transfer' the registration over (unless moving within your area). What are my options? I feel like the easiest is to just wait until July when we are back and have an address in Melbourne to then register.

I didn't realise before I'd moved registration is area specific rather than countrywide. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I don't know the answer to the registration question, but you should keep in mind there are [special requirements for taking dogs to Tasmania](http://dpipwe.tas.gov.au/Documents/Importing_dogs.pdf) if you're not already aware of them.

Comment: Hi Zach, I'm up to date on the requirements for taking dogs into tasmania but thanks for mentioning :)

Comment: Since this is about relocating, it's off topic here but would possibly fit at our sister site [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I don't know whether this question would be on topic for [pets.se] or not, but that's a possibility as well.